# Issue with jquery loader

Tags: jquery, loading

I use a .gif loader with jq after submit button.

This is the simple script :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#search_results').html('<img src="ajax_loader.gif" /> Mencari...');
    });
});
</script>
```

My problem is : the loader not show, just text `"Mencari..."` , and i have check the path of .gif and it's correct.

any missing?
thanks for the help.

**UPDATE :**
[image]

Comment: Is the image in the same directory as the page you have the javascript on? Check in the developer console if the image is loaded, or where it's trying to load the image from.

Comment: Try using `/ajax_loader.gif` as the path. It's probably at the root.

Comment: yes, i have inspect my html too. the path is correct, but the loadr can't show

Comment: Could do with a better title.

Comment: Hi, i have update my post, i insert inspect screeshot error with chrome

Answer (score 0):

seems like loading of image tooks too long - image is loaded when IMG element referencing it is already removed from DOM. Try preloading of an image with

```
var o = new Image;
o.src = "('<img src="ajax_loader.gif" />'";
o.onload = function() {
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#search_results').html('<img src="ajax_loader.gif" /> Mencari...');
});
};
```

Also don't forget to specify image's width&height.
Besides check the dom whether nothing is overlapping image (does it have enough z-index to begin shown).

Hope it would be helpfull!

Comment: Hi @sergei , thanks for the response. i have try and not working